# Code completion does not work in swift based Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: xcode, swift, code-completion

I'm having trouble with getting code completion to work when working with Swift in embedded Cocoa Touch Frameworks. All my code is in Swift.

I have a project with 2 embedded frameworks in addition to the "main app" target.
When writing code in the "main app" target, code completion and looking up symbols for various classes works like a charm.

In my Cocoa Touch Frameworks, none of this works, and I get the **"No symbols found"** popup.

The app compiles and runs perfectly, which leads me to believe this is an XCode bug. 
I've tried the usual remedy for broken auto completion (deleting derived project files), but nothing seems to alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It seems like I had to delete the ModuleCache folder in my derived data folder, not only the derived data from my project.